# Running Code View (assembly debugger) on Win7 x64

Tags: assembly, windows-7

I am using Win7 x64.

In my class, we use Win XP x32 and write program in standard MS-DOS editor, and debug our programs with Code View.

But my problem is that I can't set it up home, because I can't run Code View on x64.

I two solutions. One is to change my OS to winXP x32 or install Virtual Machine and use winXP x32 on it.

Is there maybe some other emulator/program that can do same as Code View ? any good tutorials about that?

Comment: Wow, I haven't used CodeView for 20 years. Don't see why anyone would either.

Comment: Right... I still have my "Visual C++ 32-bit Edition" CD from 1992. Just wondering how productive it is to use stuff older than that. Getting an exam is good, but not everything will be useful in the real world. (Like my CS101 with Simula and Univac 1100 assembly :-).

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but hopefully someone will find it useful.
One way to run it is to download [DOSBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/files/dosbox/0.74/DOSBox0.74-win32-installer.exe/download), it is an emulator of old-timer DOS. Since you are mentioning Code View, I am guessing that you are using MASM as well so short instructions how to run it would be as follows:

- Run DOSBox
- In the console, write something like 'mount D C:/masm' where 'masm' is a folder where you have stored your compiler and Code View (cv.exe)
- Next is command 'D:' which will make you inside your 'masm' folder
- Compile it - 'masm myfile.asm'
- Link it - 'link myfile'
- Finally, debug in the Code View 'cv myfile.exe'